# jquery.when ajax issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-deferred

Let's see my code first:

```
$.when(function(){
    //blah blah blah...
    $.post('submit.php', {name: 'John'}, function(){
        console.log('saved!');
    }, 'text');
    //blah blah blah...
})
.then( $('#data').show() );
```

What does it mean? I think it means when first function does its work (post to `submit.php` and some other works), show the `#data`. (Am I right?)

But, when I run it, it first shows the `#data` and then log `saved!` (means post finished)

Why?

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be calling `.when()` at all.
`$.post()` already returns a Defered object.
You can call `.then()` on it directly.

Comment: When it's wrap with `function` I'm almost sure it won't work.

Comment: Yes, but post data is a part of the works the function should do. It does something before and after posting..

Answer (score 0):

You can make it work like that

```
$.post('submit.php', {name: 'John'}, function(){
    console.log('saved!');
}, 'text').then( $('#data').show() );
```

or, if you want to keep using *$.when*

```
$.when(function() {
    return $.post('submit.php', {name: 'John'}, function(){
        console.log('saved!');
    }, 'text');
}).then( $('#data').show() );
```